# Prevent subprocess window from taking focus

Tags: python, window, subprocess

I have the following code:

```
with open(filename) as imgfile:
    viewer = Popen(['feh', "--scale-down", filename])

# User input here
```

My problem is that the subprocess window (image viewer) steals the focus from my input window. So the user has to click the first window to input text. Does anyone know a simple solution to change that?
I already tried different viewers. The opening and closing should be fast, because there are lots of images that are shown sequentially.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are using Linux you could maybe use xdotool. But I guess it will be hard to get this work consistently. Maybe you should consider making a GUI application.

Comment: Ok thank you. It seems to be really complicated otherwise